# Am I using python pooling properly?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pool

I have a very simple python script that reads in a ticker symbol from a list (6K+ long) and gets some data to flag unusual volume during the trading day.

If I just run a loop through each of the lines in the ticker file it takes hours to run.

Based on some googling I found a crude example of this multiprocessing and decided to try and implement it.

When I run the script it runs WAY faster but also has caused some really bizarre issues I can't see to figure out. Sometimes I'll get a redis circuitbreaker error or sometimes it'll just stop and hang near the end of the ticker file.

Any thoughts?

```
import yfinance as yf
import multiprocessing
import time
import logging

file = open("C:\\Users\\miner\\Desktop\\unusual.txt", 'w')


def main():
    read_ticker_file()


def read_ticker_file():
    file1 = open("C:\\Users\\miner\\Desktop\\tickers.txt", 'r')
    lines = file1.readlines()

    count = 0

    ticker_arr = []

    for line in lines:
        count += 1
        line = line.strip('\n')
        line = line.strip()
        ticker_arr.append(line)

    return ticker_arr


def get_historical_data(symbol):
    yahoo_ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
    historical = yf.download(symbol, period="max", interval="1d")
    average_volume_arr = historical['Volume']
    try:
        current_volume = yahoo_ticker.info['volume']
        sum_volume = 0
        for volume in average_volume_arr:
            sum_volume += volume
        average_volume = sum_volume / len(average_volume_arr)
        if current_volume > average_volume:
            volume_over_average = (current_volume - average_volume) / average_volume
            volume_over_average = "{:.2%}".format(volume_over_average)
            unusual_volume = (symbol + " - " + str(volume_over_average))
            print(unusual_volume)
            write_to_file(unusual_volume)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def write_to_file(data):
    file.writelines(data + "\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # start = time.time()
    inputs = read_ticker_file()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=20)
    pool.map(get_historical_data, inputs)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    # end = time.time()
    # print(start - end)
```

Comment: I assume the bottleneck of your procedure is the download? Do you **always** get the issues that you mentioned? Is it possible that you're sending too many queries and get blocked from your target server?

Comment: @André there isn't much support or documentation from yahoo to say for sure but I don't think so. I haven't seen any server specific errors.

Comment: What about my other two questions? Is the download the bottleneck? Do these issues always appear when you're running your code?

Comment: @André if I let it run long enough eventually I always get the Redis CircuitBreaker error. Which as far as I can tell is not related to the yahoo api.

The download is probably the bottleneck, yes

Comment: Whenever you tag a question with `multiprocessing`, you are supposed to also tag the question with the platform, such as `windows` or `linux`. Am I correct in inferring that you are running under Windows? If so, each process in the pool (all 20 of them) will be executing its own instance of `file = open("C:\\Users\\miner\\Desktop\\unusual.txt", 'w')`. Thus you will have 20 processes opening for output and writing to the same file in parallel. This is not a good thing. If it is Linux then each process in the pool inherits the already opened file descriptor and the situation is not much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, I do not believe you are handling your output to `unusual.txt` correctly. The following at least should correct that issue by having your worker function just return the record or `None` back to the main process for writing. I am using method `imap` instead of `map` so that I can lazily process the return values as they are returned. They will also now be in the order of the symbols as they appeared in the input file. In case the input file has a large number of symbols, we should not use the default *chunksize* argument, so I have provided a function to calculate a suitable value.

```py
import yfinance as yf
import multiprocessing
import time

def read_ticker_file():
    with open("C:\\Users\\miner\\Desktop\\tickers.txt", 'r') as f:
        return [line.strip() for line in f]

def get_historical_data(symbol):
    yahoo_ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
    historical = yf.download(symbol, period="max", interval="1d")
    average_volume_arr = historical['Volume']
    try:
        current_volume = yahoo_ticker.info['volume']
        sum_volume = 0
        for volume in average_volume_arr:
            sum_volume += volume
        average_volume = sum_volume / len(average_volume_arr)
        if current_volume > average_volume:
            volume_over_average = (current_volume - average_volume) / average_volume
            volume_over_average = "{:.2%}".format(volume_over_average)
            unusual_volume = (symbol + " - " + str(volume_over_average))
            print(unusual_volume)
            return unusual_volume
        else:
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None

def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # start = time.time()
    inputs = read_ticker_file()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=20)
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(len(inputs), 20)
    results = pool.imap(get_historical_data, inputs, chunskize=chunksize)
    with open("C:\\Users\\miner\\Desktop\\unusual.txt", 'w') as f:
        for result in results:
            if result:
                print(result, file=f)
    # end = time.time()
    # print(start - end)
```

**An Alternate Approach**

Again, this is not necessarily going to solve your problem other than the one you have writing to *unusual.txt*, which the above code should also handle. But it is the way that I would code the solution and work from there:

I am going "out on a limb" here not knowing how large a file *tickers.txt* is or that much about the `yfinance` package. But it seems fairly obvious that the call to `yf.download` and the file writing to *unusual.txt*, which I have already indicated in my comment above I don't believe is being handled correctly, are I/O bound "processes" that couldn't just as well be handled by a multithreading pool. It's not clear that what remains, i.e. the calculations and comparison of `current_volume` with `average_volume` are CPU-intensive enough to justify the use of the overhead of using multiprocessing for performing these calculations.

The following splits up what was a single function, `get_historical_data`, which did all the downloading and computations, into two functions, `load_historical_data_and_process` and `process_data`. Both a large multithreading pool and multiprocessing pool are created. Worker function `load_historical_data_and_process` is called for each symbol in *tickers.txt* using the mutithreading pool with function `imap`, which is a "lazier" version of `map`. That is, in case the file is large, it is not necessary to read into memory all the symbols and first build a list required by `map`; a generator function can be used. Even if the file is small, there is no real disadvantage to using `imap`. `load_historical_data_and_process` will do all the downloading necessary. For doing calculations it will used the multithreading pool that was passed to it with blocking method `apply` to invoke worker function `process_data`. It would be interesting to also get an alternate timing achieved by *directly calling* function `process_data` instead of using the multiprocessing pool. There will, of course, be very little concurrency achieved across the threads in the execution of `process_data` in this case because of contention for the Global Interpreter Lock. But depending on how much actual CPU is involved in the execution of `process_data` (I have no way of knowing), the CPU you will have saved by not having to pass arguments and results across process boundaries may be offsetting.

```py
import yfinance as yf
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool, Pool
from functools import partial
import time

def get_symbols():
    with open("C:\\Users\\miner\\Desktop\\tickers.txt", 'r') as file1:
        for line in file1:
            yield line.strip()

def load_historical_data_and_process(multiprocessing_pool, symbol):
    """ What I believe is I/O-intensive and so this runs in a multithreading pool: """
    try:
        historical = yf.download(symbol, period="max", interval="1d")
        yahoo_ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
        current_volume = yahoo_ticker.info['volume']
        # To call directly:
        #return process_data(symbol, historical, current_volume)
        return multiprocessing_pool.apply(process_data, args=(symbol, historical, current_volume))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None


def process_data(symbol, historical, current_volume):
    """ What I believe may warrant running in a multiprocessing pool: """
    average_volume_arr = historical['Volume']
    sum_volume = 0
    for volume in average_volume_arr:
        sum_volume += volume
    average_volume = sum_volume / len(average_volume_arr)
    if current_volume > average_volume:
        volume_over_average = (current_volume - average_volume) / average_volume
        volume_over_average = "{:.2%}".format(volume_over_average)
        unusual_volume_record = (symbol + " - " + str(volume_over_average))
        print(unusual_volume_record, flush=True)
        return unusual_volume_record
    else:
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # start = time.time()
    # or some suitable thread pool size:
    with Pool(processes=20) as multiprocessing_pool, ThreadPool(processes=100) as thread_pool:
        # pass multiprocessing pool to thread pool worker get_historical_data for CPU-intensive processing
        worker = partial(load_historical_data_and_process, multiprocessing_pool)
        results = thread_pool.imap(worker, get_symbols())
        with open("C:\\Users\\miner\\Desktop\\unusual.txt", 'w') as f:
            for result in results:
                if result:
                    print(result, file=f)
    # end = time.time()
    # print(start - end)
```